# How to create html/javascript table to be sortable, filterable and editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have close to 500 properties to manage in my application and I thought of listing them in a html table structured in the following way for documentation:
**Prop.Name  Prop.Type  Default.Value Prop.Description**

My html table has been started and lists all the properties.
 
But I was wondering if I could add functionality to this table. 
My requirements would be:
    1. make the table columns sortable, 
    2. add a input field to make the table filter rows if I want to easily look for a property
3. make the fields editable (if I need to make an update),
4. it has to be lightweight just use the browser

Would it be possible to do all of the above with javascript ?

Thanks again for your answers and tips,
Best regards,

Comment: yep, all possible. Try something and come back when you have a specific problem, we are not here to do all the hard work for you

Comment: 1,2 and 4 are possible. But how do you want to persist your data for 3? Do you expose a service for that?

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know if it was possible. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing impossible just you have to hardwork and combine a few jquery plugin(s).

Comment: I would recommend having a look at knockout and possibly jquery UI or kendo UI. They would be the best to work with

Comment: `contentEditable` will make it editable in extend of @Simon Verhoeven's comment. http://jsfiddle.net/wKAvs/15/

Comment: @Manoz I was thinking more along the lines of actually persisting it since he wants to use it to manage the properties of his application.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is DataTables table plugin 
https://datatables.net/

You can create, sortable, editable, etc...
And add custom filters for each columns.

I use it much in my projects, it's very useful and customizable